# visual studio web performance test missing some .csv data source content

Tags: csv, visual-studio-2015, automated-tests, performance-testing, load-testing

I have a `.csv` file that looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xiSS.jpg)

```
productid,zip,code,total
BDHS,30525,**TEST**,10
4200,75505,232,5
RT22,96817,9999,100
```

When I try to insert this `.csv` file into the Web performance test `.webtest` file as the Data Source,  I can see the value `TEST` in the code column  is missing. 
[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcDYT.jpg)

```
productid, zip, code, total
BDHS,30525,    ,10
4200,75505,232,5
RT22,96817,9999,100
```

Any idea why this value is missing?

Comment: Are the columns strongly typed? I notice that other values in the column are numbers, any chance 'TEST' isn't coming through because it doesn't match the data type for 'code'?

Comment: No, I don't do anything else now, just create the data file and try to use it as the data source.  I don't know what cause vs think it is some kind of  data type. is there any way we can have both characters and numbers in the data file?

Comment: Just checked it and the problem also exists in Visual Studio 2017. The normal answer for CSV reading issues is that fields are interpreted in much tha same way as Excel treats cell values. So leading zeros are lost and some values with `/` or `-` or `:` are treated as dates or times, and so on. The solution then is to add a space into telephone number (so `01234 567890`) and possible to add extra characters to others (so `zz12:34`) and remove the extras with a plugin. You could try these methods. But that does not explain why the field value disappears.

Comment: Thanks,  I added some extra character at the beginning of the numbers, that helps to walk around the miss value issue.  do you think this is VS bug? Thanks again.